# MongoDB .NET Driver - Use $in in the match stage

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I have two collections one is for posts (PostInfo) and one for users (UserInfo), I join two collections and I want to find the posts if the given **userid** is in **AsUser.Friends** :

```cs
var docs = await _dbContext.PostInfos.Aggregate()
                  .Lookup("UserInfo", "UserId", "UserId", "AsUser")
                  .Unwind("AsUser")
                  .Match(
                      new BsonDocument() {
                          { "$expr", new BsonDocument() {
                                  { "$in", new BsonArray(){ "$AsUser.Friends", BsonArray.Create(user.UserId) } }                                 
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  )
                  .As<PostInfo>()
                  .Project<PostInfo>(Builders<PostInfo>.Projection.Exclude("AsUser"))
                  .ToListAsync();
```

This is userinfo document :

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("62d64398772c29b212332ec2"),
        "UserId" : "18F1FDB9-E5DE-4116-9486-271FE6738785",
        "IsDeleted" : false,
        "UserName" : "kaveh",
        "Followers" : [],
        "Followings" : [],
        "Friends" : [ 
            "9e3163b9-1ae6-4652-9dc6-7898ab7b7a00", 
            "2B5F6867-E804-48AF-BED3-672EBD770D10"
        ],
}
```

I am having a problem working with the `$in` operator.

**Update**

Also, I think this would work too (from [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/)):

```
db.inventory.find( { tags: { $eq: [ "A", "B" ] } } )
```

But I can't convert this to C# format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$in` operator (logic) is incorrect, you should check whether the `userId` in the `AsUser.Friends` array as below:

```
{
  $match: {
    $expr: {
      $in: [
        "9e3163b9-1ae6-4652-9dc6-7898ab7b7a00",  // UserId
        "$AsUser.Friends"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hR7Muq1jrZe)

---

For MongoDB C# syntax,

```cs
.Match(
    new BsonDocument() 
    {
        { 
            "$expr", new BsonDocument() 
            {
                { "$in", new BsonArray() { user.UserId, "$AsUser.Friends" } }                                 
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: How do you convert Mongo Query to MongoDB C# syntax ?

Comment: If you have (install) MongoDB Compass, you can translate with: Select database & collection --> Go to aggregations tab --> Input your stage(s) --> Click Export to Language button --> Choose the language (C#). It will translate the MongoDB query to C# syntax which will be set of BsonDocument(s).

Answer (score 0):

$expr is only required if you are doing a much more complicated expressive query, performing transformations and applying functions - for example calculating the average of and array and performing a match against that.

All you need is simple find syntax in Match - and in MongoDB shell: `find({"asuser.friends":user.UserId})`

or in your case:

`Match( new BsonDocument( "AsUser.Friends",user.UserId))`

In MongoDB A match against an array will match either any element or a whole array.

Comment: However your approach to this is also super inefficient as this will look up the user info for every post before checking the friends list in it a huge amount of computation if you aren't filtering the posts. I fear you are doing the JOIN in the wrong direction. You should get the user, query against  users to get those they are friends with first, then join each person to their posts. Essentially you have the wrong tables either side of a LEFT  outer join.